# Rewrite Helper Class that implements interface

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, overrides, helper

What I want to do is removing the price from the options in the bundled products in the cart.

I made a folder `Mage/Bundle/Helper/Catalog/Product/Configuration.php` in my local folder and i copy/paste all the code from the core there.As we all know because Magento reads first from local it reads my changes first.
It works but I feel it's not the correct way to do it??
I know how to rewrite Blocks/Models/Helpers/ but that specific Helper also implements interface so you can't just change one function.You have to implement all.
Am I wrong with what I have done?
If so please point me the "Magento" way.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is very simple you have to override the this class and that class implement that interface.

Fist you need to create the module of that for that `app\etc\modules\Keyul_Test.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Keyul_Test>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Keyul_Test>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Create the following structure `app\code\local\Keyul\Test` and create two folder like `etc` and `Helper`

create the config file `app\code\local\Keyul\Test\etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>
    <helpers>          
        <bundle>
            <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_configuration>Keyul_Test_Helper_Bundle_Catalog_Product_Configuration</catalog_product_configuration>
            </rewrite>
        </bundle>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

create the `app\code\local\Keyul\Test\Helper\Bundle\Catalog\Product\Configuration.php`

```
<?php
class Keyul_Test_Helper_Bundle_Catalog_Product_Configuration extends     Mage_Bundle_Helper_Catalog_Product_Configuration
{
  // override your method hear.
}
```

Hope you got Solutions.

Comment: (1) declaration file should *not* contain version number;   (2) the version number in the config file is superfluous;   (3) `test` classgroup & prefix declaration are superfluous; (4) the data helper is superfluous